# highcharts 2.2.5 not displaying graphs

Tags: highcharts

I need to upgrade my highcharts.js file from 2.1.4 to 2.2.5 (because I want to use
the useHTML property in the tooltip and it is supported from 2.1.7) 
the problem is that when I upgrade, highcharts doesn't work anymore (doesn't draw the graph)

you can view this in here (mouseover one of the black boxs)
working example 2.1.4 http://s-maof.com/PRO/index3.php?fkapp=2

and not working example 2.2.5 here http://s-maof.com/PRO/index4.php?fkapp=2

Comment: Actually neither of the links you provide have a working Highchart

Comment: you have to mouseover one of the black boxs